# How to recreate default Activity change animation in Compose?

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I want to achieve this kind of animation.

[image]

I managed to achieve a horizontal shift, but I do not understand how I can darken the old screen.

A similar effect appears in Compose when opening `NavigationDrawer` or `AlertDialog` - the entire screen behind is darkened. What is the correct name for this effect, and if it has a public API?

Here is my current code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    val animationDuration = 500
                    val startDestinationEnterAnimation: (AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> EnterTransition) = {
                        slideIntoContainer(
                            towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                            animationSpec = tween(animationDuration),
                            initialOffset = { it / 2 }
                        )
                    }
                    val startDestinationExitAnimation: (AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> ExitTransition) = {
                        slideOutOfContainer(
                            towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                            animationSpec = tween(animationDuration),
                            targetOffset = { it / 2 }
                        )
                    }
                    val destinationEnterAnimation: (AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> EnterTransition) = {
                        slideIntoContainer(
                            towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                            animationSpec = tween(animationDuration),
                        )
                    }
                    val destinationExitAnimation: (AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> ExitTransition) = {
                        slideOutOfContainer(
                            towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                            animationSpec = tween(animationDuration),
                        )
                    }
                    NavHost(
                        navController = navController,
                        startDestination = Constants.SCREEN_MAIN,
                        builder = {
                            composable(
                                route = Constants.SCREEN_MAIN,
                                enterTransition = startDestinationEnterAnimation,
                                exitTransition = startDestinationExitAnimation
                            ) {
                                MainScreen(
                                    onClickSettings = {
                                        val route = Constants.SCREEN_SETTINGS
                                        navController.navigate(route) {
                                            popUpTo(route) {
                                                inclusive = true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                            composable(
                                route = Constants.SCREEN_SETTINGS,
                                enterTransition = destinationEnterAnimation,
                                exitTransition = destinationExitAnimation
                            ) {
                                SettingsScreen(onClickBack = {
                                    if (navController.currentBackStackEntry?.lifecycle?.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
                                        navController.popBackStack()
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this look through the navigation animation Api - but you can fade in a black full screen box over the top of the mainscreen composable when you navigate to screen settings.

I've tested the code below and it looked okay. It's important that the black box code is below the main screen code so that it renders in front of the main screen composable.

I've set the easing to EaseOutCirc but you might find a nicer easing here
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary#EaseOutCirc()

```
Box(){    
    val showbox = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    MainScreen(
        onClickSettings = {
            showbox.value = true
            val route = Constants.SCREEN_SETTINGS
            navController.navigate(route) {
                popUpTo(route) {
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }
        }
    )
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = showbox.value,
        enter = fadeIn(tween(750, easing = EaseOutCirc))
        ) {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Black))
    }
}
```